# How to calculate multiple variables with precondition

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, error-000539, precondition

I want to do multiple "calculate values" in ModelBuilder.
To make it simple let´s take only 2 simple calculations:
1) calculate sine from angle to variable "MySinus"
2) use this value in a second calculation to calculate a hypothenuse in a triangle.

I want to keep the result of calculation 1) in a separate Variable "MySinus", so doing 1) and 2) in a single step is not an option (the real calculation i have to do is more complicated with 15 and more connected calculations plus geoprocessings)

It is clear, that calculation 1) must be done before calculation 2).
I could use a precondition, but what if the result is a negative number? Then the 2nd calculation won´t be executed, because precondition is "false".

[image]

Calculation Value 1:
Expresssion: math.sin(-math.pi*0.55)

Calculate Value 2:
Expression: %abc%*5

What I tried already:
- Calculation Value 1) data type to "variant"
with result:
Executing (Calculate Value 1): CalculateValue math.sin(-math.pi*0.55) # "Any value"
Start Time: Mon Jan 12 11:39:10 2015
Value = -0,987688340595138
Succeeded at Mon Jan 12 11:39:10 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,28 seconds)
Executing (Calculate Value 2): CalculateValue -0,987688340595138*5 # Double
Start Time: Mon Jan 12 11:39:10 2015
Value = 
Succeeded at Mon Jan 12 11:39:10 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,05 seconds)

(Second Value isn´t really calculated !!!)

- Calculation Value 1) data type double
  Result:
  Executing (Calculate Value 1): CalculateValue math.sin(-math.pi*0.55) # Double
  Start Time: Mon Jan 12 11:40:50 2015
  Value = -0,987688340595138
  Succeeded at Mon Jan 12 11:40:50 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,05 seconds)
  Executing (Calculate Value 2): CalculateValue -0.987688340595138*5 # Double
  Start Time: Mon Jan 12 11:40:50 2015
  The process did not execute because the precondition is false.
  Succeeded at Mon Jan 12 11:40:50 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,00 seconds)
- Change Expression in Calculation 2) to: float(%abc%)*5
  Result:
  Executing (Calculate Value 2): CalculateValue float(-0,987688340595138)*5 # Double
  Start Time: Mon Jan 12 11:42:12 2015
  ERROR 000539: Error running expression: float(-0,987688340595138)*5 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  TypeError: float() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Failed to execute (Calculate Value 2).
Failed at Mon Jan 12 11:42:12 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,05 seconds)

(it seems that there is a problem with comma recognized as parameter delimiter)

- Change Expression in Calculation 2) to: float("%abc%".replace(",","."))*5

Executing (Calculate Value 1): CalculateValue math.sin(-math.pi*0.55) # Variant
Start Time: Mon Jan 12 11:53:47 2015
Value = -0,987688340595138
Succeeded at Mon Jan 12 11:53:47 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,07 seconds)
Executing (Calculate Value 2): CalculateValue float("-0,987688340595138".replace(",","."))*5 # Double
Start Time: Mon Jan 12 11:53:47 2015
Value = -4,93844170297569
Succeeded at Mon Jan 12 11:53:47 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0,05 seconds)

Finally !!!!!

Is there any simplier way instead of this there an back conversion??
(Of course I could use a python script for all this calculations, which seams to be straight way. But how to do it easy in ModelBuilder?)

Answer (score 2):

I got it working using a python script - which has two output parameters - the sinus and a boolean. The boolean i use as the precondition. 
See [Use value of Field in Calculation in Modelbilder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122501/use-value-of-field-in-calculation-in-modelbilder)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

1. (1) Creates your MySinus value which can be positive or negative.
2. Have another Calculate Value tool (called Test) that returns a
   boolean. True if MySinus is positive and False if it is negative.
3. Test output becomes the precondition to your calculate
   Hypotenuse?

Comment: Not sure if this works - how do i chain 2. after 1.?

I got it working using a python script - which has two output parameters - the sinus and a boolean. The boolean i use as the precondition.